# Getting a char from a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have a String variable named `List`.I want to get the first char of the String which is in the `List`.
The problem is, that I cannot use the `charAt()` function on the `List`.
Here is my effort so far:

```
List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
```

`testList.get(3).chatAt(0)`;

Comment: As a start it might be helpful to state the programming language you are using and [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119695/how-can-i-add-tags-and-where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-tags-on-stack-overflow) the question with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have given should work (apart from the typo). It retrieves the 4th item in the list, which we know is a String because have defined the list as a list of Strings, and then gets the first character of that String. It will obviously break if there are not 4 things in the list, or if the String doesn't have any characters in it.

```
List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.get(3).charAt(0);
```

You can make things a bit clearer by declaring the String as a variable before you call charAt on it.

```
String s = testList.get(3);
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

Comment: I just realized, that I have a List ... sorry I messed it up.

Comment: The error suggests that the get() method is returning an object, and not a String. However, this shouldn't be the case, as you have declared that your list contains strings using List<String>. If you want a quick fix, then you could cast the output of the get method to a String before calling charAt on it: ((String)testList.get(3)).charAt(0). But I would suggest you try to get the generics correct instead. Can you post the exact code that you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Methods `get(String s)`
 is not available for arrays in Java, probably you confused it with methods of Java Collection Framework (list).
If you have an array of string you must first access on the element with `array[i]`
 and after call the method `charAt(int index)`.
Finally you must use `array[i].charAt(index)`
where **i** is the position in the array to the string that you search and **index** the index of character you must search in the string.

Comment: Yes that works with Arrays but unfortunately I wrote my question wrong. I actually used a List insted of an Array.

Comment: @CodingProgression ah ok, I reply at your first question. :/ leedsunited92 already solve your problem ;)